# Object access by a string key returns any

Tags: javascript, flowtype

We want to get value from [Exact object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types) by:

**I** Existing literal.

```
// Correct
function foo(arg: 'bar', obj: {|bar: 42|}): number {
  return obj[arg];
}
```

**II** Missing literal.

```
// Error
function foo(arg: 'baz', obj: {|bar: 42|}): number {
  return obj[arg];
      //    ^ Cannot get `obj[arg]` because property `baz` is missing in object type
}
```

**III** `string` type. Why this is valid?

```
// Correct
function foo(arg: string, obj: {|bar: 42|}): number {
  return obj[arg];
}
```

Why Object access by a string key returns any?